# FOS Rest Bundle not returning proper json

Tags: php, rest, symfony, facebook-php-sdk, fosrestbundle

[image]

As you can see, the 'cover' and 'parking' index are both arrays. But when i return the response I get something like this.
[image]

The 'cover' and 'parking' key are both not showing values in the json response.
So this is my controller:

```
    public function getPageInfoAction($page)
        {

            $request = (new FacebookRequest(
                $this->initAppAction(),
                'GET',
                "/{$page}"
            ))->execute();

            $graphObject = $request->getGraphObject();
            //dump($graphObject);
            //die;
            return $graphObject->asArray();
}
```

This is my config.yml file

```
#fos_rest
fos_rest:
    param_fetcher_listener: force
    view:
        view_response_listener: 'force'
        formats:
            xml:  true
            json: true
        templating_formats:
            html: true
    format_listener:
        rules:
            - { path: ^/, priorities: [ html, json, xml ], fallback_format: ~, prefer_extension: true }
    exception:
        codes:
            'Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\ResourceNotFoundException': 404
            'Doctrine\ORM\OptimisticLockException': HTTP_CONFLICT
        messages:
            'Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\ResourceNotFoundException': true
    allowed_methods_listener: true
    access_denied_listener:
        json: true
    body_listener: true
    disable_csrf_role: ROLE_API
```

So how can i return the correct json response?

Comment: Please convert your screenshots to text only

Comment: post exact output instead of screenshot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I found an answer to this.
As my array also had an object as value, the serializer was returning empty json object while returning the response to json. So to solve that I checked whether the key is object or not

```
 foreach($options as $t){
        if(isset($graphObject[$t]))
            //
            $pageInfo[$t] = gettype($graphObject[$t])== 'object'?(array)$graphObject[$t]:$graphObject[$t];
    }
```